# Error when compiling a Numba module with function using other functions inline

Tags: python, numpy, numba

[Numba documentation specifies that other compiled functions can be inlined  and called from other compiled functions.](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jit.html) This does not seem to be true when compiling [ahead of time](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html).

For example: here are two functions that compute the inner dot product between 2 vector arrays, one of them does the actual product, the other makes the inline call within a loop:

```
# Module test.py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, float64

@njit(float64(float64[:], float64[:]))
def product(a, b):
    prod = 0
    for i in range(a.size):
        prod += a[i] * b[i]
    return prod

@njit(float64[:](float64[:,:], float64[:,:]))
def n_inner1d(a, b):
    prod = np.empty(a.shape[0])    
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        prod[i] = product(a[i], b[i])

    return prod
```

As is, I can do `import test` and use `test.n_inner1d` perfectly fine. Now lets do some modifications so this can be compiled to a .pyd

```
# Module test.py
import numpy as np
from numba import float64
from numba.pycc import CC

cc = CC('test')
cc.verbose = True

@cc.export('product','float64(float64[:], float64[:])')
def product(a, b):
    prod = 0
    for i in range(a.size):
        prod += a[i] * b[i]
    return prod

@cc.export('n_inner1d','float64[:](float64[:,:], float64[:,:])')
def n_inner1d(a, b):
    prod = np.empty(a.shape[0])    
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        prod[i] = product(a[i], b[i])

    return prod

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cc.compile()
```

When trying to compile, i get the following error:

```
# python test.py
Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Untyped global name 'product': cannot determine Numba type of <type 'function'>
File "test.py", line 20
```

## QUESTION

For a module compiled [`ahead of time`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/pycc.html), is it possible for functions defined within to call one another and be used inline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reached out to the numba devs and they kindly answered that adding the `@njit` decorator after `@cc.export` will make the function call type resolution work and resolve.

So for example:

```
@cc.export('product','float64(float64[:], float64[:])')
@njit
def product(a, b):
    prod = 0
    for i in range(a.size):
        prod += a[i] * b[i]
    return prod
```

Will make the `product` function available to others. The caveat being that it is entirely possible in some cases that the inlined function ends up with a different type signature to that of the one declared AOT.